# How to create dynamic number of variables from split array in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which I am splitting using numpy `split_array`. I then assign variables `a,b,c,d` to these split chunks

```
num_partitions = 4
# number of variables needs to be the same as num_partitions
a,b,c,d = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
# do work on a,b,c,d
.
.
.
```

My question is, how can I dynamically create these variables and assign them to the split chunks in case `num_partitions` were to change? So for example, if `num_partitions` were to change to 100 then I would have to manually type out variables `var_0,...,var_99` in my current method, which I don't want to do for obvious reasons. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not have them as dict or list of values?

Comment: Just use a dictionary. Polluting the global namespace like you want to is, almost always, a horrible idea.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was thinking if there was some way to do this other than using dictionaries. But using a dictionary the answer would be simple and something like `num_partitions=4; chunks_dict = {i:np.array_split(df, num_partitions)[i] for i in range(len(num_partitions))};`

Comment: Why do you need variables? Or even dictionary keys?  `split` already gives you a list.  Usually a list is easier to use, especially if the names or keys are in some sort of 'numeric' order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list or dictionary to store your split array.
Using a list is easy:

```
chunks = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
```

If you like to use a dictionary, like your's in the comment, don't call `array_split` multiple times, but use `zip`:

```
chunks = dict(zip(range(num_partitions), np.array_split(df, num_partitions))
```

Answer (score -2):

Most times if not always using exec to assign variables is a very bad idea and I highly discourage you from doing so. But since you asked here's the code. Better practice would use a dictionary instead of dynamically assigning variables.

```
import string
chars=string.ascii_letters
num_partitions = 4
for i,j in np.array_split(df, num_partitions),range(num_partitions):
    exec("{}={}".format(chars[j],i))
# do work on a,b,c,d...
.
.
.
```

Please note that this will only support up to 52. Just make the chars list longer.

Comment: @Zero I agree with you as well. It would be much nicer just to use a dictionary... Most if not always using exec for assigning variables is a bad idea. But that was their question so I answered it.

Comment: @Zero I've added a disclaimer to the beginning. :)

Answer (score -3):

If your using a long list of data its best to use a python container like a class,dictionary or the array itself.  Automatically creating global variables could accidentally overwrite built-in keywords and create problems.

The best way to manage is to use a list because it best represents the data.

```
arr=list(np.array_split(df,num_partitions))
arr[0]#same as using variable 'a'

arr.sort()      #sorts it
arr.reverse()   #reverses it
arr.index(val)  #finds the position of a value in the index
```

classes are good if you want to really, really want to use letters:

```
class contain:
    def __init__(self,arr):
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            key=''.join([chr(int(j)+97) for j in str(i)])
            setattr(self,key,arr[i])

 c=contain(arr)
 c.a    #same output as arr[0]
 c.ba   #same as arr[11]
```

Any of these resolve to the same location in memory as a variable and can be used in all the same places.  Just a matter of what’s best fits your needs.

Best of luck